# pandas DataFrame conditional string split

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column of influenza virus names within my DataFrame. Here is a representative sampling of the name formats present:

1. (A/Egypt/84/2001(H1N2))
2. A/Brazil/1759/2004(H3N2)
3. A/Argentina/126/2004

I am only interested in getting out A/COUNTRY/NUMBER/YEAR from the strain names, e.g. **A/Brazil/1759/2004**. I have tried doing:

```
df['Strain Name'] = df['Original Name'].str.split("(")
```

However, if I try accessing `.str[0]`, then I miss out case #1. If I do `.str[1]`, I miss out case 2  and 3.

Is there a solution that works for all three cases? Or is there some way to apply a condition in string splits, without iterating over each row in the data frame?

Comment: Well, it looks like after futzing around, I found that doing a `.apply(lambda x: max(x, key=len))` did the trick, since I was basically looking for the longest string in the split.

Comment: To moderators: should I leave this post around still? Please feel free to edit/modify/delete anything that isn't useful to the community.

Comment: What are you splitting the string on? Will your longest-string approach break on viruses like A/New York/107/2003?  Depending on where you access the viruses from, this may or may not be a concern, because some databases offer the option to replace spaces with "_".

Comment: @iayork: I'm splitting the string on a parentheses "(", because I wanted to remove the parentheses from the strain name.

Comment: @EdChum: Thanks for the note. I will post an answer + code, according to your recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, based on EdChum's recommendation, I'll post my answer here.

Minimal data frame required for tackling this problem:

```
Index    Strain Name               Year
0        (A/Egypt/84/2001(H1N2))   2001
1        A/Brazil/1759/2004(H3N2)  2004
2        A/Argentina/126/2004      2004
```

Code for getting the strain names only, without parentheses or anything else inside the parentheses:

```
df['Strain Name'] = df['Strain Name'].str.split('(').apply(lambda x: max(x, key=len))
```

This code works for the particular case spelled here, as the trick is that the isolate's "strain name" is the longest string after splitting by the opening parentheses ("`(`") value.

Comment: Something like `df["Strain"].str.strip("()").str.split("(").str[0]` should also work, I think.  Could also write a regex and use `extract`, although here that's probably more trouble than it's worth..

Comment: I will, but I have to wait 2 days in order for that to happen. Thanks though, Ed!